I can’t post questions from mobile
Very related to this bug but the bug here only has one of those issues and they haven’t been fixed as of writing.

When I write a question on my mobile phone (Safari, iOS 15, iPhone 13) and press the button that says Review your question, nothing happens, which means I have to go to my computer if I want to post it. I can still post answers and edit things just fine.

@testing-for-ya forgot to say I’m using Safari

I believe SO only supports Safari on iOS 17.4. See: https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/

@testing-for-ya it’s on iOS 15 as I stated in the question

I closed this because, given the links in the answer there, it seems like they'd be uninterested in fixing a bug with an unsupported version of Safari+iOS. If that's for some reason not the case, as you did link to an instance about a year and some change ago where they were, I'm happy to reopen this. Circumstances around the choice to fix that issue were likely different than they are today, though.

@Spevacus I added an exact duplicate as well.
